# Hi , i am using Windows 10 (64 bit) , Firefox Version 53 . My code is for Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium

I am trying to open a page using Selenium Webdriver using Firefox Browser (version 53) and getting below error. I understand that below erroe exist only for Firefox browser version  above 47 .

However i tried to fix it for Version 53 using below solution and it failed. Please help.

**Code**

```
 `System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\V\\Browser\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
```

**Console Log**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'THAKURV-PC', ip: '10.0.0.58', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:658)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:104)
    at SPS.SPS_One.main(SPS_One.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:192)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService.start(XpiDriverService.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    ... 7 more

Comment: instaed of "webdriver.firefox.marionette" use "webdriver.gecko.driver"

Comment: Thanks kushal it helped

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use GeckoDriver (webdriver.gecko.driver) if you are working with Firefox version 53 (basically after Firefox v 47.0.1).

Steps:

1. Download GeckoDriver v0.16.1
2. Use Selenium 3.4
3. Try this code

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\Firefox\\geckodriver.exe");

   FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
   options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"); //This is the location where you have installed Firefox on your machine

   FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
   driver.get("http://www.google.com");
   ```

You can refer this article for complete setup process - [Selenium GeckoDriver Setup](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/selenium-3-0-launch-firefox-with-geckodriver/)

Comment: After 47.0.2 to be precise. Using GeckDriver doesn't yield you great success in automation, it doesn't wait for page to load when you click the button.

Comment: Thank Anish and Raj